# nesting c++11 range loops for finding combinations

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, iterator, combinations

finding combination involves two loops over the same container.

```
the first iterates over elements:
  pick an element
  iterate over the elements on the left
    print the first and the second iterated elements
```

so here is a wrong example:

```
vector<int> vec;
for(size_t i=0; i< 10 ; ++i) vec.push_back(i);
for(auto i : vec)
{
  auto j = i.increaseBy(1);
  for(j : vec) cout << i << j << "\n";
}
```

in this question, i'm interested if there is more to syntax of range-loops than just a simple way to iterate over elements. there isn't much documentation on c++11.

Comment: It is for iterating over *all* the elements of a container. You can't define your own start or end point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to iterate over `[(v[i], v[j]) | i <- [0..v.size()], j <- [0..i]]` (using pseudo-code with list comprehension syntax), then you can do the following with a little help from Boost.Range:

```
for(auto i: boost::irange(0, v.size()))
    for(auto j: boost::irange(0, i)) {
        // use v[i] and v[j]
    }
```

Beyond the example though, the answer to your question is that no, the range-for statement doesn't do much magic. It's also not extensible. However, the good news is that there's another way to look at it: the range-for statement might be quite dumb, but ranges are allowed to be as smart as they want.

This means that while a range-for may only be able to iterate over elements of a range, that range doesn't have e.g. to map to an actual, existing container, contrary to what you seem to be expecting. For instance, this

```
namespace A = boost::adaptors;
for(auto&& e: A::strided(v, 2)) foo(e);
```

calls `foo` on every other element of `v`. The work is here done by `strided`, not the range-for statement.

I can't think of a concise way to express your example in just one range even with the help of Boost.Range. That doesn't mean it's impossible though, and I did investigate some form of list comprehension in C++ in the past. The tools to express it are not here today however.

Comment: +1 Very nice. It's all about ranges :-) All that's missing from Boost is a sort of "product range", I suppose.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes. You can filter and transform already, expressing a cartesian product through iterators was indeed my big obstacle when I tried.

Comment: I suppose that you would need much stricter requirements on the iterator categories... the existing range adapters probably all manage to preserve the category.

Comment: @KerrekSB Boost.Range is on top of Boost.Iterators, which does include a proposal to extend/refine the current iterator (quasi-)concepts.

Comment: to complete, `#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>`  and i just did `for(auto i:v) for(auto j:boost::irange(i,v.size())) { cout << i << j;}` thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that what you're after is a collection of *pairs* of vector elements.

That's not what the range-based loop is for. Range-based loops are for iterating over an entire collection, looking at each element exactly once. Don't use them for anything else. Just because it's a new, added language feature doesn't mean you have to throw away everything else you ever knew. The new feature *enrich* the language, they don't *replace* it.

Here's how to get unique pairs:

```
for (auto it1 = vec.begin(), end = vec.end(); it1 != end; ++it1)
{
     for (auto it2 = std::next(it1); it2 != end; ++it2)
     {
         std::cout << "[" << *it1 << ", " << *it2 << "]\n";
     }
}
```

If you also want to include the diagonal elements (`it1, it1`), simply replace the second initialization by `auto it2 = it1`.